# Alfa AWUS036NHA not recognized as interface

Tags: usb, driver, networking, wireless-adapter

Since today my wireless network adapter refuses to work. Yesterday everything worked perfectly fine but for some unknown reason it stopped working. When I plug in the device I get a very limited response from `dmesg`.

```
[ 1174.268765] usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using dwc_otg
[ 1174.389973] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
[ 1174.390000] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[ 1174.390017] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: UB91C
[ 1174.390033] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[ 1174.390049] usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: 12345
```

What could I try to get my adapter working again?

Comment: That's it, isn't it? Doesn't the ***AWUS036NHA*** have an ***Atheros*** chipset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions at https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc which basically boil down to the following:

- add `non-free` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` line
- do `apt-get update` to update the list of available packages
- do `apt-get install firmware-atheros`
- make sure your configuration files for wifi are correct
- reboot
- get a beer for a job well done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already used a backup file system and everything worked again. I hope your answer will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

The above instruction to run  apt-get install firmware-atheros followed by restart worked for my ALFA AWUS036NHA plugged into a Raspberry Pi with Kali Linux Installed.

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2017.3"
VERSION_ID="2017.3"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kali.org/"


cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.50-v7+ (root@builder) (gcc version 4.9.4 (Linaro GCC 4.9-2017.01) ) #1 SMP Wed Aug 30 11:08:41 CDT 2017
```